# Section Scroll Animated counter

Tags: jquery

This is how i am creating Animated Counter on scroll.
and this is not working on Mac Google Chrome if any one knows please guide me what is the problem with this code.

```
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {`enter code here`
    var oTop = $('.countbox').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
        $('.num').each(function () {
            var $this `enter code here`= $(this), countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
            $({
                countNum: $this.text()
            }).animate({
                countNum: countTo
            },
                {
                    duration: 2000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function () {
                        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $this.text(this.countNum);
                    }
                });
        });
        a = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please review your snippet.  There are a couple "`enter code here`" statements in there that are very oddly placed.

Comment: Try Google Chrome dev tools: ctrl+shift+I and look for errors.